# i want to get listview's id of selected item

Tags: android, listview

I am performing listview's selected item id. but i'm unable to get item id. please help me..

```
public class ViewAllActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  ListView lv;
  DbHelper dbh;
  String selected;
  final String ar[]={"Delete","Update"};
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_all);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    dbh = new DbHelper(ViewAllActivity.this);

    final ArrayList<DoctorPojo> arraylist = dbh.getData();
    ArrayAdapter<DoctorPojo> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<DoctorPojo>(ViewAllActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arraylist);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {
            AlertDialog.Builder alert=new AlertDialog.Builder(ViewAllActivity.this);
            alert.setTitle("Which Action You Want to Perform...!!!");
            alert.setItems(ar, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    selected=ar[which];
                    if(selected == "Delete") {
                        //Toast.makeText(ViewAllActivity.this, " Delete is pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Intent i=new Intent(ViewAllActivity.this,DeleteActivity.class);
                        i.putExtra("id", arraylist.get((int) lv.getSelectedItemPosition()).toString());
                        startActivity(i);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(ViewAllActivity.this, " Update is pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });
            alert.create().show();
            return false;
        }
    });
    }

}
```

here i cant get my listview's id. i want it because i want to pass that id because i want to delete that perticular record.and also want to perform update operation. so for that i want id os that listview's selected item. so please help me.

Comment: in onItemLongClick use arraylist.get(position); there you will get the DoctorPojo object then you will get DoctorPojo id...

Comment: if you want to remove use arraylist.remove(position); then adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)  -- here the `long id` is the id

Comment: @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
            {
                String r=arraylist.get(position).toString();
                final int p=arraylist.indexOf(r);

Comment: sorry sir it gives me understandable id i have tried it

Comment: i have tried getselecteditem(), getselectedItemposition(), and also getselectedID(), even i want get perfect output so please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
DoctorPojo mPojo=arrayList.get(position);
 i.putExtra("id",mPojo.getId());
```

Comment: sir i want to update my list view as soon as delete operation performs on database.